# Edit Json File in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, yaml

I want to replace the values in manifest.json. My manifest.json file looks like

```
{
  "uat1": {
    "database": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
     },
    "services1": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "p_database": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
     },
    "p_services": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "Build_d": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      }
     },
  "uat2": {
    "database": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
     },
    "services1": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "p_database": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
     },
    "p_services": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "Build_d": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      }
     }
```

Whenever there will be any update on uat1 database (or any other component), it will update the manifest file with version and sysdate. My output manifest.json will look like

```
{
  "uat1": {
    "database": {
      "artifact_version": "12.0.3",
      "date": "04/08/2021 19:50:14"
     },
    "services1": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "p_database": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
     },
    "p_services": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "Build_d": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      }
     },
  "uat2": {
    "database": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
     },
    "services1": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "p_database": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
     },
    "p_services": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      },
    "Build_d": {
      "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
      "date": "sysdate"
      }
     }
```

I am writing a python code, but values not getting properly displayed:
I am running python like **test.py 12.0.3 uat1 database**
My code looks like:

```
import sys
import json
from datetime import datetime

version = str(sys.argv[1])

env = str(sys.argv[2])
script = str(sys.argv[3])
now = datetime.now()
sdate = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(sdate)

print("%s %s %s" % (version, env, script))

with open("C:/Users/lohapri/PycharmProjects/RFOS/manifest.json", "r") as f1:
    data = json.load(f1)
f1.close()
#print(data)

for k1, v1 in data.items():
    if k1 == env:
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            if k2 == script:
                v2['artifact_version'] = version
                v2['date'] = sdate
            print(v2)
            with open("C:/Users/lohapri/PycharmProjects/RFOS/manifest.json", "w") as f2:
               for i in k1:
                 json.dump(v2, f2, indent=4)
```

Th Output in manifest.json I am getting is:

```
{
    "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
    "date": "sysdate"
}{
    "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
    "date": "sysdate"
}{
    "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
    "date": "sysdate"
}{
    "artifact_version": "0.0.1",
    "date": "sysdate"
}
```

Please tell me how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You have dict and there is no need to iterate through it
And you need to dump json just once

```py
data[env][script].update(
    artifact_version = version,
    date = sdate
)

with open("C:/Users/lohapri/PycharmProjects/RFOS/manifest.json", "w") as f2:
    json.dump(data, f2, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just parse it, update the necessary value, and write it back to the file.

```
with open("manifest.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)

d[env][script] = {"artifact_version": ..., "date": ...}

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    try:
        json.dump(d, f)
    except Exception:
        raise
    else:
        os.rename(f.name, "manifest.json")
```

If you aren't concerned about `manifest.json` being truncated before successfully writing the new data, you can reduce the third step to

```
with open("manifest.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, to 'edit' a `json` file, you have to load the whole file in with: `data = json.load(f1)`, then perform the transform, then write the write the whole lot out again:

```py
with open("C:/Users/lohapri/PycharmProjects/RFOS/manifest.json", "r") as f1:
    data = json.load(f1)
#no close needed
#print(data)

for k1, v1 in data.items():
    if k1 == env:
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            if k2 == script:
                v2['artifact_version'] = version
                v2['date'] = sdate
            print(v2)

with open("C:/Users/lohapri/PycharmProjects/RFOS/manifest.json", "w") as f2:
  json.dump(data, f2, indent=4)
```